# Setting component prop values in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm coming from `React` and trying to understand how I can set values of component props in the `NavigationContainer` of my `React Native` app. Please note that I'm using `React Navigation 5`.

For example, my `<Car color="red" />` component expects the color to be set.

How do I do this in `React Navigation 5`?

My `NavigationContainer` looks like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
   <DrawerNav.Navigator>
      <DrawerNav.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <DrawerNav.Screen name="MyCar" component={Car} />
   </DrawerNav.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

I need to set the `color` for the `<Car />` component.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it right. You can pass the props like this.

```
<Car color="red" />
```

Other way is to pass through navigation.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Car",{color:'red'})
```

and then in car component you can access it like this.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.color
```

Comment: What I was asking is how I'd do it within the `<NavigationContainer>`? Can I use function inside the `component`?

Something like `<DrawerNav.Screen name="MyCar" component={() => <Car color="red" />} />`?

Comment: Why you want to pass in NavigationContainer? You can pass it from where your navigation action triggers

Comment: Because I want to set the initial values that I'll get from my redux store.

Comment: I could do it where I trigger the navigation too but I just wanted to learn how to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Sometimes we might want to pass additional props to a screen. We can
>   do that with 2 approaches:
>
> 1. Use [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and wrap the navigator with a context provider to pass data to the screens
>      (recommended).
> 2. Use a render callback for the screen instead of specifying a `component` prop:
>
> ```
> <Stack.Screen name="Home">
>   {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={someData} />}
> </Stack.Screen>
> ```
>
> > Note: By default, React Navigation applies optimizations to screen components to prevent unnecessary renders. Using a render callback
> >     removes those optimizations. So if you use a render callback, you'll
> >     need to ensure that you use
> >     [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) or
> >     [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)
> >     for your screen components to avoid performance issues.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#passing-additional-props

Comment: I'm also getting an error for `ownProps` when I try to pass props to a `class` component. Is `ownProps` not used in `React Native`?

Comment: I don't think that's related. Check if you have any mistakes in your code using Redux.